# How to extract data from a Postman response conditionally and use it in next request

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I want to extract data from a Postman response conditionally and use it in next request.

This is my `JSON` response :

```
{ 
    "tags": [ 
    "common" 
    ], 
    "launchUrl": [ 
    { 
    "bacId": "default", 
    "launchUrl": "NA" 
    } 
    ], 
    "_id": "5b167cf878ab370336b27588", 
    "name": "IBM Security as a Service_Test RD", 

    }, 
    { 
    "tags": [ 
    "common" 
    ], 
    "launchUrl": [ 
    { 
    "bacId": "default", 
    "launchUrl": "NA" 
    } 
    ], 
    "_id": "5b41b8df36dec2733de9999e", 
    "name": "Automated API Service", 

    } 
    ] 
}
```

What I want is based on "name" I want to get the id(Which is random) and use it my my next request. Ex: If name is "Automated API Service" get the id , store it in a variable and use it in next request.

Any suggestion would really help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you have added is not valid but If it's what I think it is, this should set the value.

```
_.each(pm.response.json(), (arrItem) => {
        if (arrItem.name === "Automated API Service") {
           pm.environment.set("ID", arrItem._id) 
        }
    })
```

If you add this to the `Tests` tab, you will be able to use `{{ID}}` in the next request.

Comment: Hi @Danny Yes I have added part of Json Object. But this is working find. Thanks for your help.